# phpmyadmin - there is no style at all

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've installed phpmyadmin and when I turn on I can't see part of style and I don't know why. I even checked if some of css files don't load or something. No every thing is okay.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this yet?

Comment: Yes, but I had to dig in code so I'm not sure if good solution

Comment: I'm facing this in 2023 in a docker-compose installation -_-

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me. Turns out when I was originally copying the files to apache/htdocs (windows) i was cutting and pasting. I stopped process and then decided to copy. This caused the files not to be completely transferred.
You should redownload the files and then recopy them.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: I am posting this as an answer until I can get more information.**

I need more information to be able to tell you anything. I'm not sure if any of the following applies to you, but here is where I would start trying to debug this problem.

First, what browser are you using?

If you're using **Firefox**,

1. Go and install the [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) add-on.
2. Right-click anywhere in phpMyAdmin and then click "Inspect Element with Firebug"
3. View the **Net** tab, and then click **CSS**. You may need to click Enable and then refresh the page first.

If you're using **Chrome**,

1. Simply right-click anywhere in phpMyAdmin and click "Inspect Element".
2. View the **Network** tab click **Stylesheet**. You may need to refresh the page to see anything here.

If you're using another browser, go download Firefox or Chrome because I can't (won't try to) help you.

From here, you should notice if anything is coming up as anything other than `200 OK` or `304 Not Modified`. If you see any entries with `404 Not Found`, then you'll at least have something to go on. Please update your question with whatever you find.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing, and followed this temp answer but there is nothing to view. Everything seems fine, but there are no styles for phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem related to something sistemistic. I had this problem with the Centos webpanel. My sistemist friend said it was something about mapping.

ps: at the beginning I could just find out that if you rename the config.inc.php and run /setup path the css of the backend are visible. But I cannot get why this problem happens.